# Why have I received 16 invisible reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

In my question posited yesterday on the [origin of indirect object placement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/570318/origin-of-stating-indirect-object-by-sentence-structure-and-no-pronoun), I early on received 16 reputation. However, I have not been able to figure out where these points come from. Have I been given them incorrectly? I have attempted viewing it both through my profile as well as via the timeline, but cannot figure out how this happened.

Comment: That Q got 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes (leaving a net score of 2). Each UV is worth 5 pts, so 4*5=20; each DV is worth -2 pts, so 2*-2=-4, and 20-4=16. When you have 2k rep you will be able to see vote breakdowns too. SO will give you notifications for rep-increasing events, but typically not for rep-decreasing ones. So often you’ll see those rolled up together.

Comment: @DanBron Each upvote is worth 10 points whether it's a question or answer; the scoring was changed last year.

Comment: Yesterday you earned 38 reputation points. 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes is 36. And 2 points were awarded because you accepted someone's answer.

Comment: Dan Bron and Mari-Lou A both answered my question. The reason I was unable to understand where it came from, was that I only saw my net result of 0 up- and downvotes. If you write up an answer (i.e. what you commented), I will happily upvote the effort and select it. For some reason, I was unable to see these up- and downvotes in the question’s history as well, but I suppose that too is part of the restrictions I have when I have too little reputation.

Comment: Click on your user box in the title bar to bring up your profile, select "Activity", then under the grey boxes, select "Reputation" to see where your rep points have been allocated or deducted. If you click on "Graph", you'll see your daily totals; click on a day's column to see (underneath the graph) a list of the individual actions that earned or lost you the rep points. :-)